# How to hide BottomNavigationView when recylerview scrolls up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

Hello there I want to hide bottom nav when recylerview scrolls up but not when the recylerview is scrolled down and when the recylerview stop I want the bottom nav to appear
also like a slide animation like how a bottom sheet has

I have one main activity in which I have given bottom nav and a fragment container as an Include the fragment container contains all of my fragments

Here is my code

> Note if anyone wants more reference of the code please tell me i will
> update the question

ok i have used `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` in bootom nav xml but its not working

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        layout="@layout/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_view" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**bottom_nav_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">


</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CoordinatorLayout` to achieve this "scroll-hide" feature:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout    //root Layout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView    //or RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
```

app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
app:menu="@menu/main" />

```
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Demo: https://youtu.be/3Gpeg6M82n4

Comment: brother recyclerviews are in different fragments which are used with fragment container and bottom nav is in main activity not on every fragment individually